# Showing Different Code on Pages With Different Layouts

Tags: pages, javascript

I have pages and posts on a WordPress site.

The pages have various layouts. Parent pages are following a 2-column (maincontent + right sidebar) layout while child pages have a one-column layout (no sidebar).

I want to display a JavaScript code on one-column layout, and a different JavaScript code on 2-column layout.

Must also add that one-colum has a custom field "one-col" and 2-column is the default layout. Not sure if it's possible to add codes based on custom fields.

Theme: WooThemes, Canvas.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_js_one_col_wpse_107240() {
  if (is_page()) {
    $pobj = get_queried_object();
    if(!empty(get_post_meta($pobj->ID,'one-col',true)) {
      wp_enqueue_script(/* ... */);
    } else {
       wp_enqueue_script(/* ... a different script ... */);
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_js_one_col_wpse_107240');
```

1. [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will get you the page information. It will
   be a `WP_Post` object on a "Page". `global $post` should probably
   work too, but this is cleaner.
2. Use the `WP_Post` object information to check for the [custom meta
   field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). enqueue scripts accordingly. You don't say what the value
   of `one-col` is so I checked for any value at all.
3. Hook the whole thing to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: +1, as usual, but one sidenote: `!empty(get_post_meta($pobj->ID,'one-col',true))` requires PHP 5.5+ while WP's current requirement is 5.2.4

Comment: @JohannesPille : hmmm... why does that require PHP 5.5? What have I missed? Do I need to save the `get_post_meta` output to a variable first?

Comment: Yep. Before 5.5 [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) would only accept variables. Since 5.5 it supports any expression. Hence caching the return of `get_post_meta()` in a variable before checking for emptiness would support PHP versions below 5.5...  (That's my understanding anyhow. Not saying I couldn't be wrong.)